# Type assertion vs properties

Tags: typescript

I've noticed the following behavior:

```
interface User {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

let user:User = {
    name: "Aaron",
    age: 99
}
```

If I omit `age: 99` I get a compile error. *This is the behavior I expect.*

However:

```
function putUser(user:User):void { }

putUser(<User> {
    name: "Aaron"
});
```

I get no compile error for missing non-optional property `age`.

In fact in my real code-base I've found that with <strike>casting</strike> **type assertion** I can at times add completely wrong properties to the object literal, but I wasn't able to reproduce this behavior in a simple case like above.

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

---

**Edit:** Omitting the assertion works, thanks @Amid. However, where I ran into this as an issue was in this kind scenario:

```
interface User { name: string; }

function putUser(user:User):void { }

interface Musician extends User { instrument: string; }

putUser(<Musician> {
    name: "Bob Dylan"
});
```

The issue is that I want to validate the `Musician` object, but `putUser` only expects the base `User` object. I thought the type assertion would give me better type safety, but in this case it actually *reduces* type safety.

---

**Edit #2**

It looks like I can get what I wanted using a generic type constraint, which actually *looks* an awful lot like my type assertion:

```
function putUser<T extends User>(user:T):void { }

putUser<Musician>({
    name: "Bob Dylan",
    instrument: "Guitar"
});
```

In this case it seems it will make sure the object literal is exactly an implementation of `Musician`.

Comment: Looking at the spec, `<User>obj` is not a cast, but rather an assertion that `obj` has type `User`. Type assertions are not checked at runtime, see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#4.16)

Comment: Yes you're right I called it a cast but it's an assertion... is there a "real" cast, then?

Comment: It's one of the [documented](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#typescript-16) ways to bypass "strict object literal assignment checking".

Comment: Check my updated answer. I think it shows how to get what you want to achieve.

Comment: Wow, I should have just waited for your answer, I just edited in the same thing to my question. :) Thanks, you really cleared it up.

Comment: Worth mentioning, type assertion and its hazards : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you are using [type assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html) here. That basically overrides all typescript type checks. If you remove
< User > part - compiler will give you error you expect

EDIT:

This is what you want:

```
interface User { name: string; }

function putUser<T extends User>(user:T):void { }

interface Musician extends User { instrument: string; }

putUser<Musician>({
    name: "Bob Dylan"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You made a type assertion. You would prefer to use type assertions when you communicate with external systems (like requesting API) when you have the shape of data you're going to receive but no own source of it.

The typescript type assertion are quite smart. It won't allow you to make completely wrong things. Here's an example:

```
interface Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

function process(box: Point) {}

let empty = {};
let part = { x: 3 };
let full = { x: 3, y: 5 };
let vague = { x: 3, y: 5, z: 7 };

process(empty); //type mismatch, got {} expected {x, y} 
process(part); //type mismatch, only {x} expected {x, y}
process(null); //no type mismatch, argument can be null
process(full); //full match
process(vague); //still works, but the function is not aware of "z" field.

process(<Point>empty); //assertion valid, object can be a Point instance
process(<Point>"123"); //wrong assertion, expected object instead of string
process(<Point>[]); //wrong assertion, expected object instead of array
```